# Start Camel route in suspended state

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to build Camel routes that starts in suspended mode?
I'm looking so to say "declutch" at start up, then at some stage quickly start processing messages by just calling `resumeRoute(routeId)`

I could perhaps just create the route and then quickly call `suspendRoute(routeId)`, after the route has been created, but at that stage, it would probably have consumed some messages (for instance in the case of JMS routes or polling consumer routes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generally, you'd just disable the route by using [autostartup(false)](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html)...

I assume you are asking though because you need the route started (warmed), but not active.  In that case, then you should be able to use a custom [route policy](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html) and some external variable to get this behavior

Comment: Thanks. I could probably get something to work with route poilicies. I have thought of `autostartup(false)` option but would actually like the routes to be in suspended mode.